# How can I include an invitation to an Isaac Newton Institute program to my CV?

Tags: research-process, cv, workshop

I would like to know how to include invitations to highly-regarded research programmes in a CV such as the ones being held in the Isaac Newton Institute. These invitations are commonly paid. That is, accommodation, travel and per diem funding is provided. During these programmes different workshops are held in the Institute and the idea is to connect with different people around the world that work on different disciplines and that solve an specific problem.

PS: I have gone to Cambridge and already participated of the programme.

Answer (score 1):

You should put it in the part of your CV where it fits. Put it with your courses if it is like a course, put it with your workshop participation if it is a workshop.
I've seen some CVs contain a section for grants and awards, which perhaps this could fit into, but only make a new section on your CV if you have several items to put into it.

Comment: Actually, a section with a single item should be fine for something prestigious.

Answer (score 0):

I have separate sections for peer reviewed conference participation versus invited participation. I wouldn't call travel and per deim 'paid', I don't consider it a real invitation without travel being paid. But I do have a category for industrial and governmental invited talks, and where those have a big honorarium I put "(paid)" after the talk title. I explain this immediately under the section header, that most of these talks are not paid unless otherwise indicated.

Since you are a new researcher, you might not want to have a separate category in your CV (yet), so instead say under the workshop participation header "peer reviewed unless otherwise indicated" and then next to this entry, maybe put in bold face **invited**.